# AWS Cognito keep authenticated session in web view

Tags: javascript, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We have a native Android app where we are using the the latest version of the Cognito SDK to authenticate the user.

The problem we have is that the Android app uses a Web view and in this web view we will need to fetch the current cognitoUser with its authenticated session.

We are using the latest Cognito javascript sdk in the web view.

How do we share the auth between 2 clients that uses the same user pool?

**Update 04/10-2017**

I managed to bypass this by sending everything Cognito related i had in my local storage as query string parameters. Then "in" the webview i saved the settings to that local storage.

It is not right but it works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now been in contact with persons that are experienced working with Cognito.

The judgment was that we can bypass this by sending all Cognito related values as query parameters to the application behind the web view.

The application in handling the web view will then take all those values and save them to local storage.

**Problems I had:**
I found out that if you have multiple Clients you will have to pass the `clientId` of the application behind the web view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible. The web-view has its own storage that is not shared with the device storage.

So the user context - users tokens, login state etc - is not shared between the webview and the Android SDK on the device